# 1995 Dodge Viper

Tags: engine, transmission, maintenance, dodge, viper

So my friend is interested in this 1995 Dodge Viper he's seen on a pre-owned showroom and I have some questions that I'd like to ask.

- What kind of questions related to that specific car should we be asking the dealer?
- What things should I look for when inspecting the car?
- Are there any question regarding maintenance of that car that I should be asking the dealer?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'd go into it assuming the car has been abused at some point or another. How many miles are on it? Does it have a service history?  If he's financing it I would probably stay away. I'm sure it would be awesome to own a viper, but a 20 year old viper?

Comment: @Ben About 10k miles. Service history is a question I must ask, jotted it down.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer all of your questions but I can tell you there are no recalls on OEM parts.

There is a single recall on the vehicle related to [aftermarket brake parts](http://www-odi.nhtsa.dot.gov/owners/SearchResults?searchType=PROD&prodType=V&targetCategory=A&searchCriteria.model=VIPER&cmplCount=3&rclCount=1&invCount=1&tsbCount=19&activeTab=0&stats=63765%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C19%2CVIPER&makeStats=&jsonBaseURL=%2Fdownloads%2Ffolders%2F&searchCriteria.model_yr=1995&searchCriteria.make=DODGE&searchCriteria.prod_ids=63765&submit=Go) from several manufacturers.

[This post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24231/in-the-us-how-do-i-tell-if-a-car-is-in-good-condition?answertab=oldest#tab-top) has excellent guidance on what to check when procuring a new used vehicle.

Most dealerships will allow you to take the car to a mechanic in order to get a basic inspection to check for error codes via OBDII and perhaps even do a compression test on the motor.  I would recommend that.

Best of luck